# How to say something is being done?

Tags: grammaire

How can we express that an action is in the process of being done, besides using "en train de" as this doesn't always make sense.

For example, "people are dying, we need to do something".

Or, "there are crimes being committed against humanity".

Comment: Its the main use of the present tense in French. For a longer answer see [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/18768/358)

Comment: Do you have an example where "en train de" does not make sense ? For me, "en train de" is always OK for translating present progressive.

Comment: I agree with XouDo, we can say:.    Des personnes sont en train de mourir, nous devons faire quelque chose.      Ce sont des crimes contre l'humanité qui sont en train d'être commis.

Answer (score 3):

This [lawlessfrench.com link](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/etre-en-train-de/) might answer your question.

So

> French doesn't have a verb form equivalent to the present progressive. Normally, you just use the simple present in French (je parle) to express both the English simple present (I speak) and the present progressive (I am speaking).
>
> When you want to insist on the current, ongoing nature of an action in French, you can use the expression être en train de[...]

I do believe you can use

*Les gens meurent, il faut faire quelque chose.*

as well to express

*People are dying, we need to do something.*

Comment: The problem is people who false think (not their fault) that just the present in French is not enough. Most times it i.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, one of the clearest ways would be saying:

> Les gens sont en train de mourir, nous devons faire quelque chose.

In French, we do not have a form only to express the "process of being done", generally we use the *présent de l'indicatif*:

> Les gens meurent, nous devons agir.

Comment: Sometimes, to stress the fact that it is happening, English just as French would add “Right now, /En ce moment même, ” prior to “people are dying.../les gens meurent...”.