# Tenses in subordinate clauses that correspond to an “-ing” form in English

Tags: grammaire, verbes, temps-grammatical

I'm trying to figure out how to talk about actions there were, will be, would be (il y avait, il y aura, il y aurait...) and so on in French, where in English we would use a verb in the -ing form.

For example, I think that these translations are correct:

- *There were lots of phones ringing.* –> *Il y avait beaucoup de téléphones qui sonnaient.*
- *There will be lots of animals sleeping.* –> *Il y aura beaucoup d'animaux qui dormiront.*

Am I right in saying that the verb has to match the tense of the *il y a* construction?

But what about with the sentence “There would have been people eating if we had arrived earlier”? Would both verbs be in the passé conditional, like this:

> Il y aurait eu des gens qui auraient mangé si on était arrivés plus tôt.

According to deepl.com (translator) this is correct, but it seems clunky to me. Or perhaps it is correct but there's another, more common way of phrasing something like this?

Comment: Pardon me. I flagged this Q as being too broad. As a metter of fact, just too many topics (completely unrelated) are questioned here. (Particular uses of *il y a* / concordances / conditional clauses... not to mention the title of the question.

Comment: @aCOSwt I agree but we could suggest that the OP rephrases their question around one of their topics before having it closed. OP's probably not an English speaker either. I'm pretty sure the way to express the English -ing form in French has already been asked.

Comment: Two questions and their answers about "Translating English sentences which use -ing verb forms to French" [How to say something is being done?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25040/358) & [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18774/358) to the question [How to say “I am taking an exam” in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/18765/358)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How would you suggest rephrasing the question? I'm not sure I understand why these are wrong, or indeed what the alternative phrasing should be. If someone could translate my sentences into french using the correct construction, or tell me the rule to follow here, that would be great. 

In the english language, the use of "ing" is absolutely everywhere and there will always be situations that seem to be outside of the usual rules. For me, this is one such situation.

Comment: I suggest "Question about a particular -ing form" and corresponding tense in the "subordinate clause"  for an "il y a" construction. It is even better to make two separate questions of this (easy to do).

Comment: @Indigo Have you looked at the questions already present on the site? There have been numerous questions about how to express the English -ing form (I only pointed to two), so if you ask question about that say why they do not fit your purpose here.  Just choose **one topic** for your question. Match the question title to the content of the question. Have you read the purpose of the SE sites ans how to ask questions ? Some of the points to remember I suppose is - one question at a time (but there are no limits in the number of questions) - no duplicates.

Comment: I vote to let this question open, as the author tries to rephrase it. Help him.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right in saying that the verb has to match the tense of the *il y a* construction?

No! That is fundamentally wrong!

Two conjugated verbs! That implies two propositions! Each one having its own meaning in a given time reference => Each to its own! Each one its own tense!

Because, if the two propositions are part of the same sentence, one could assume that the two propositions are in some way related. Some logic is supposed to govern **that particular** relationship.

**That particular logic** will then **force** some *concordance* between the tenses expressed by the verbs. *Concordance* meaning that they are both compatible. Not necessarily identical.

If I need to say that ***Hic & Nunc*** I can assert that **there are** (Hic & Nunc) FSE contributors who, *nachdem* **will** comment this answer, I can write that :

**Il y a** sur FSE des contributeurs qui **commenteront**...

Comment: Tu pourrais ajouter la traduction d'une de ses phrases, p.e. *Il y aurait eu des gens en train de manger si on était arrivés plus tôt.*. Qui auraient mangé ne va pas ici...

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous : Tu as raison mais en fait, je viens plutôt de flagger la question as too broad. Et en plus totalement de rien à voir avec le titre.

Answer (score 0):

Those translations are all correct except for the last one, which should be sommewhat different; that is, as written, it is not quite correct.

- There would have been people eating if we had arrived earlier.
- Il y aurait eu des gens en train de manger si on était arrivés plus tôt.

In a continuous tense the sense of the verb "manger" is different, more "factual".

- À midi il aurait mangé et non pensé à aller se coucher. (prendre un repas)
  *At twelve he would have [eaten/had a meal] and not have thought of going to bed.*
- À midi il aurait été en train de manger. (action de mâcher et d'avaler de la nourriture)
  *At twelve he would have been eating.*

However, "prendre un/son repas" is also used in a "continuous  tense fashion", that is with "en train de", a locution saying that the action is going on at the time referred to.

- Ils étaient en train de prendre leur repas à la terrasse d'un restaurant.

No, you are not right to think the tense of the verb has to match necessarily the tense in the "il y a" construction, **unless** you understand that "il y a" is used to confer coincidence in time. To cite the [TLFi (**IV A**)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir), "il y a" is used as a "morphème de présentation" but we should say rather "il y a/il y a eu/il y avait/ il y aura/il y aurait/…"; what is presented to the interlocutor **exists** at the time conferred by the tense or exists hypothetically. "**Il y a**" means roughly "**there exists**". There might not be a coexistence then of the situation or thing claimed to exist at a particular time and the action that is related to it; in that case thes tenses can be different. I won't list all the possibilities below as I feel unsure about some of them.

- Il y avait beaucoup de téléphones qui sonnaient. (*coincidence in time in the past*)
- Il y a beaucoup de téléphones qui sonnent. (*coincidence in time in the present*)
- Il y aura beaucoup de téléphones qui sonneront. (*coincidence in time in the future*)
- Il y aurait beaucoup de téléphones qui sonneraient. (*coincidence of hypothetical situations*)

- Il y a beaucoup de téléphones qui sonnaient (toute la journée en ce temps-là). (*The phones do exist now and at least in the past they were ringing.*)
- Il y a beaucoup de téléphones qui sonneront. (*The phones are here now, but they are nog going to be ringing necessarily now.*)

*No sense seems to fit these constructions.*

- Il y avait beaucoup de téléphones qui sonneront.
- Il y a eu beaucoup de téléphone qui sonneront.

It is only needed now to change the type of the verb "sonner" and instead of an action consider a state: "sonner faux". When you use this verb you do not state an action and more than one tense is possible.

- Il y avait des mots qui sonnent/sonnaient faux dans son parler.
- Il y a des mots qui sonnent/sonnaient faux dans son parler.
- Il y aura des mots qui sonnent faux dans son parler.
- Il y aura des mots qui sonneront faux dans son parler.